# Different results when iterating through string vs printing a specific position (C)

Tags: c, string, cs50

I am learning C, and the problem I am running into is if I iterate through the string up to and including `strlen()`, I am expecting to get the null character (nothing) printed, but instead, I just keep getting '.' — whereas if I print `array[strlen(array)]`, I get nothing (null character). What is going on?

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <cs50.h>

    int main(void)
    {
         char *mystring;
         printf("Enter a string: ");
         mystring = GetString();

         //Prints '.' for mystring[i] when i = strlen(mystring)
         for (int i = 0, j = strlen(mystring); i <= j; i++){
              printf("The %dth character is: %c.\n", i+1, mystring[i]);
         }

         //Skips the line printing nothing ('\0')
         printf("The last char is %c\n", mystring[strlen(mystring)]);

         return 0;
    }
```

Comment: What do you think `%c` means?

Comment: `s[strlen(s)]` references the terminator, not the last char,  of a null-terminated string. And you don't "fix" it by using `strlen(s)-1`, as using that for a dereference index will invoke *undefined behavior* if `s == ""` (empty string).

Comment: Reading your question, it looks like you forgot that you print a `.` in your `printf` statement: `"is: %c."`.

Comment: @KerrekSB its just a place-holder (format) for a character data type correct? '\0' is a char. Not sure why this is an issue

Comment: @WhozCraig I am trying to see why the for loop prints '.' instead of the terminator (using %c), while the printf outside of the loops does print the terminator (nothing) (using %c).

Comment: Thanks everyone. One more thing though, just for testing purposes, i let i increment to a value higher than strlen(mystring)+1 expecting to get an error or some wierd jazz from the next memory block, but i kept getting '.' It looks as if once i reach '\0' i just stay on it even if i increment the iterator.

Comment: @user96454 Accessing an array to 1 more than the array limits could have _any_ value. Accessing an array to more than 1 past the array limits could kill the program (UB).

Answer (score 2):

You are actually printing this dot every time (right after `%c`): `"The %dth character is: %c.\n"`. When your input is the null character `%c` won't print a thing since it's null and all you see is the dot afterwards.

Comment: oh, haha that was dumb of me. Thanks for clarifying that.

Answer (score 0):

For `\0` nothing will be printed. But you have `.` after `%c` in `printf` statement-

```
printf("The %dth character is: %c.\n", i+1, mystring[i]);
```

Due to that `.`, when printing `\0` it will print only `.`(For null it wont print anything).

```
printf("The %dth character is: %c\n", i+1, mystring[i]); //remove that . and try!
```